# What is the best way to detect and store the timezone the client of a web app is in?

Tags: c#, javascript, timezone

I have a multi-timezone web application that stores all of the datetime values in UTC in the database, when actions happen on the server, I can easily convert the time into UTC.

However, when a client enters a time or time span, what is the best way to detect and store it?

I am currently doing the following:

1. Get the value of Date.getTimezoneOffset() (javascript)
2. Post that to the server-side code via the ICallbackEventHandler on Page.
3. Store that value in the session
4. On any subsequent request, calculate the output/input datetime value using the client's timezone.

Regardless of the actual implementation, this seems like an in-elegant solution.  Does anyone have a better method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was doing something very similar, but I now think I prefer to use *javascript* to convert all times to local on the client-side. The server will give all times in UTC in the generated page, and the *javascript* will convert it once the page loads.

This eliminates confusion on the server-side code, as I always know what time it is (UTC). On the client-side, I'm using *jquery* and the `each()` function to format all the time values at once. I write out each of the times as a *Unix* time in a hidden field to make this easy to process with *jquery*.

The only problems I see with this method is that:

a) I don't have a really good date/time formatting routine yet in *javascript*, and

b) if the user has *javascript* turned off, then it doesn't work.

Comment: This is a neat solution, and one I considered.  The only reason I shied away from it was a "countdown timer" scenario, like when a user has X hours remaining to do an action.

I sort of felt like that logic should happen on the server, but I guess it would be fine in javascript.

Comment: Anything that's a time limit on the user should definitely be checked against the server. The countdown timer seems related to this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198049/prevent-js-alert-from-pausing-timers
It's a similar idea, that client side validation is vulnerable to cheating.

Comment: @Mnebuerquo good point.  I'll probably have to go with a hybrid method.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the "header" property of the HttpRequest Object to query the "If-Modified-Since" header sent by the client. This header should contain a date in a format that includes the timezone of the client, like this:

```
If-Modified-Since: Sat, 29 Oct 1994 19:43:31 GMT
```

a simple substring extraction will give you the timezone code. 
However, I'm afraid not all browsers are coherent in sending that header, so you should experiment a bit about it.

regards,
Fabrizio

Comment: That's a really cool solution! I wish it did work in all browsers, because I wouldn't have to use any javascript!  What I see eventually is an HttpModule or a class that derives from Page that would store that variable on the first request. Thanks!

Comment: How does that work exactly? It looks to me like the header has gmt instead of a timezone. Does that mean the client's computer is set to GMT or does that mean that the browser is always using GMT for the request?