# Why do JS modal message boxes pause countdown on setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, settimeout, alert, confirm

I have encountered an unexpected behavior of JS `setTimeout` when modal dialog windows like `alert` are open and I would like to know the reason behind it.

I expected setTimeout(fn,10000) to mean "check current time periodically and when it is greater than Now + 10000ms fire the event handler that will invoke the passed 'fn' function". This would be logical, seeing how we pass the timeout measure as 'ms from now'. But, apparently, the countdown on `setTimeout` is a literal countdown and  will be paused while a modal window is open.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //alert A
    alert("10 seconds have passed for the first setTimeout")
}, 10000);
setTimeout(function(){
    //alert B
    alert("Wait for 15 seconds and press OK");
},1000);
```

I would expect alert A to display immediately after you close alert B (presuming you waited for 15 sec. to do so), since alert A timeout was just for 10 sec and they have already passed. Practice, however, shows that countdown to alert A is simply paused while alert B is open and it will show only after approx. 9 more seconds have passed after you've closed alert B, no matter how long B was open.

This does not seem logical.

**Update.** I'm definitely not the only one confused here, because this behavior of pausing the timeout occurs in Chrome and Internet Explorer, but not Firefox. Firefox executes the behavior I expected - if you wait for 15 seconds on alert B - alert A pops out instantly whenever you close it.

Comment: This is one of the reasons why `alert`s are not good especially with timing functions.

Comment: @soktinpk We use things like Bootbox for alerts in our projects, but there are times when it is not applicable, like when you need to warn user about unsaved data upon closing page. I can't imagine people running into trouble because of this behavior too often, yet still, a major behavior difference between the three big browsers is interesting.

Comment: Warning a user about unsaved data is a perfectly valid use for `alert` and/or `confirm`. However, why would you want to wait a little before `alert` shows?

Comment: I don't intend to wait, the situation is this: let's say you set a timeout for 5 sec and then user tries to leave. Message pops up and he spends 5 sec reading it before he decides to stay and finish his work. In FF the timeout will fire immediately once he closes, but in IE and CR it will wait another 5 sec, bringing the total timeout to 10 sec.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I doubt there is a definitive answer on why both IE and Chrome put a pause on pending timers until `alert` has been dismissed, and Firefox doesn't. I believe it's just because there is certain freedom in interpreting the [W3C's specs for `alert`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html):

> The alert(message) method, when invoked, must run the following steps:
>
> 1. If the event loop's termination nesting level is non-zero, optionally
>      abort these steps.
> 2. Release the storage mutex.
> 3. Show the given message to the user.
> 4. Optionally, pause while waiting for for the user to acknowledge the
>      message.

Step 4 (the *pause*) is further explained [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/webappapis.html#pause):

> Some of the algorithms in this specification, for historical reasons,
>   require the user agent to pause while running a task until a condition
>   goal is met. This means running the following steps:
>
> 1. If any asynchronously-running algorithms are awaiting a stable state,
>      then run their synchronous section and then resume running their
>      asynchronous algorithm. (See the [event loop](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/webappapis.html#event-loop) processing model
>      definition above for details.)
> 2. If necessary, update the rendering or user interface of any Document
>      or browsing context to reflect the current state.
> 3. Wait until the condition goal is met. While a user agent has a paused
>      task, the corresponding event loop must not run further tasks, and any
>      script in the currently running task must block. User agents should
>      remain responsive to user input while paused, however, albeit in a
>      reduced capacity since the event loop will not be doing anything.

So, the event loop gets suspended in any case. The callback of the longer timeout doesn't get invoked while the alert is still visible and modal. Had it not been this way, all kinds of nasties might be made possible, like multiple alerts on top of each other.

Now, can you tell from the above specs if the timer countdown should be suspended for the lifetime of the alert, or should rather be fired as soon as the alert has gone? I can't, and I'm not even sure which behavior would be more logical.

What I'm sure about is that you shouldn't be using JavaScript alerts for anything else but debugging purposes. Alerts do allow to suspend script execution (while some asynchronous operation like XHR is taking place in the background), but they're quite unfriendly to the user. The right approach would be embrace asynchronous code, using promises and, possibly, [ES6 generators/`yeild`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23234019/1768303) (if you're after the linear code style).

The following question is highly related and some alternatives to `alert` are discussed there:

- [Prevent js alert() from pausing timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/198049/prevent-js-alert-from-pausing-timers)

Answer (score -1):

alert is UI blocking and since Javascript is single threaded it will block anything from running until the dialog is dismissed.

Comment: You meant to say 'alert is synchronous'. I know that, but that does not answer the question. My original expectation was for alert A setTimeout to check current time right after the function in alert B returns and the JS thread is unblocked, at which point it would see that over 10000 ms have passed and execute alert A.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need to, you can use your own timer.

```
var now = Date.now();
function alertA(){
    //alert A
    alert("10 seconds have passed for the first setTimeout")
}
setTimeout(function(){
    //alert B
    alert("Wait for 15 seconds and press OK");
    setTimeout(alertA, 10000 - (Date.now() - now)); // Subtract the time passed
},1000);
```

You can wrap this in a utility method:

```
function alertDelay(messages, timePassed) {
  if (typeof messages !== "object" || messages.length === 0) return;
  if (timePassed == null) timePassed = 0;
  var firstMessage = messages[0];
  var now = Date.now();
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert(firstMessage.message);
    alertDelay(messages.slice(1), Date.now() - now);
  }, firstMessage.delay - timePassed);
}
```

Usage:

```
alertDelay([
  {message: 'Message 1', delay: 1000},
  {message: 'Message 2', delay: 5000},
  {message: 'Message 3', delay: 10000}
]);
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a workaround yet, I'm just curious as to why. This code definitely wouldn't help much, since setTimeouts are set in different places. The only workable way I can think of off the top of my head would be to overload window.setTimeout to use fastest possible setInterval inside, maintain a list of callbacks with due-dates and check them vs Date.now(). Should work, but I don't think there is a project that would really need such precision. Anyways, as I said, more interested in 'why?' then 'how to fix?'.

Comment: @IvanKoshelew I think [dnharjani's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26487531/3371119) does a good job of explaining why: `alert` may block the thread. It really depends on implementations of `alert`. You can't rely on it when using timing functions.

Comment: I don't think that answers the original question. I know why it prevents setTimeout callback while it is open - no surprise there. What I don't understand is why it continues waiting extra after it is closed. Why only FireFox does it the way I expected? Should I submit this as a bug to other browsers bugtrackers? I mean, since the behave differently with the same code - one of them must be wrong. The question is, which one and why?