# How to save times, timezone question

Tags: asp.net

I'm building an ASP web app that stores appointment times; it'll be used in different timezones. I'm currently saving an appointment in the database as a datetime field. Do I also need to add a field to save the timezone? What's the best option to solve these multi-timezone issues?

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179834/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-and-store-the-timezone-the-client-of-a-web-app-is and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11975/handling-timezones-in-storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most common approach is to save all date/times as UTC in the database, then apply a user specific timezone offset to them when displaying them.

If I am in GMT+10, and I choose 10:00 AM as a time for a certain event, store the time in the database as midnight.

When a GMT+5 person comes to view the site, get the UTC time out of the database and add their offset to it (5 hours) to display the time at 5:00 AM.